# Is it a crime to falsely claim that you’re older than 16 in order to get vaccinated?

Tags: united-states, fraud, vaccination

The Pfizer vaccine is only approved for people over the age of 16 in the US. Let’s say a person is 13 years old and wants to get vaccinated. Would it be a crime for them to arrive at a vaccination site, claim that they’re 16 and receive the vaccine? Currently many vaccination sites don’t require any ID to get vaccinated, so you won’t have to produce any false documents.

Comment: "many vaccination sites don’t require any ID to get vaccinated": where?  In New York you have to prove eligibility, which means proving that you live in New York or work in New York, and that you work in one of several qualifying occupations or are above a certain age.  It's possible to prove eligibility through employment using documents that don't disclose age, but eligibility based on age requires showing evidence of age.

Comment: @phoog in Washington (personal experience). Other eligible people are reporting a similar story. This fact inspired this question.

Comment: Washington's eligibility criteria are still somewhat restricted.  I assume from "personal experience" that you have been vaccinated in Washington or accompanied someone else who was vaccinated there.  Did they not require proof of eligibility?

Comment: @phoog I became eligible in the latest vaccination tier. No proof was required from me and no proof was ever required from anyone except for the initial health worker tier. I did have it on hand but no one asked to see it.

Comment: You didn't have to say which eligibility criterion you satisfied?

Comment: @phoog you did not. Not even the words "I satisfy the eligibility criteria". You walk in, say your name and DOB, sit in line, get your shot and leave. You do have to tick the "I satisfy the criteria" checkbox on the appointment booking website though.

Comment: Ok, does the appointment booking website indicate that the law requires submissions made by the user to be truthful?  The New York sites do, as far as I recall.  If the Washington site includes a similar declaration by the user, subject to some penalty for misrepresentation, then your answer lies in the enforceability of that penalty.

Comment: @phoog the question is whether or not you're actually "stealing" anything by lying about your age. It could be argued that the government does want to give it to every single American regardless of age but they don't for now due to having no medical trial results. So by lying about your age you're merely taking up a risk on your own rather than stealing something. But I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: @phoog it would be kind of similar to lying to your doctor about how bad you feel in order to get access to an experimental drug that's only supposed to be given to terminal patients. If the drug is not in short supply, who is actually the victim of your lies?

Comment: "The question is whether or not you're actually "stealing" anything by lying about your age":  The question isn't about stealing.  It does not contain the word "stealing."  If you're only interested in theft or fraud, to the exclusion of other crimes such as perjury, then you have asked the wrong question and you should ask a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Depending on the state, this would likely be classified as fraud, theft by deception, larceny by trick, or something similar.

Generally speaking, these laws make it a crime to obtain the property of another person through some factual misrepresentation. By misrepresenting your age to obtain a vaccine from a person who would not give it to you knowing your true age, you would be guilty of the offense.

Comment: I wouldn't be sure about that at all. You would be most likely right if someone who isn't US resident got a vaccine by deception - for example, the UK health service is supposed to pay for my vaccine, not the USA. But the reason why a 13 year old US resident wouldn't get the vaccine isn't the cost of the vaccine, but the fact that it is untested and considered too risky.

Comment: @gnasher729, that argument explains why they made it illegal to provide the vaccine while knowing that the recipient is under-age.  It doesn't explain why you think it wouldn't be illegal for recipients to lie about their age.

Comment: @RayButterworth I also don't understand the argument. It's like saying it wouldn't be illegal for a 13-year-old to lie to acquire experimental chemical weapons; after all, the reason we don't give 13-year-olds chemical weapons isn't the cost of the weapons, but the fact that they are untested and considered too risky.

Comment: @gnasher729 The exact reason why the victim relied on the false information to make their decision is (mostly) irrelevant, as long it is reasonable and not against public policy. A dishonest and intentional misrepresentation of material facts with intention to gain an otherwise unavailable benefit is fraud in most common law countries. But here whether it is an actual crime may also depend on the value of loss for the victim.

Comment: Obtaining a medical treatment and properly paying for the treatment is not the same as illegally obtaining property is it? It may be more analogous to claiming pain in order to receive anti inflammatory drugs. As long as you properly paid for it (assuming no insurance involved), and do not abuse the drug (let's say you want a stash for future pain) hard to say this is theft.

Comment: But no one's really paying for the vaccine, are they? A better comparison might be to laws prohibiting people from taking an entire stack of free newspapers; there's a limited supply, but people don't get to just take however much they want.

Comment: @bdb484 I'm not aware of such laws.  Do they in fact exist?

Comment: They do. Here's California's: https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=490.7.

Comment: Here's Maryland's: https://casetext.com/statute/code-of-maryland/article-criminal-law/title-7-theft-and-related-crimes/subtitle-1-crimes-involving-theft/part-i-theft/section-7-106-newspaper-theft

Comment: And these thefts can also be prosecuted under regular theft laws. Here's a smattering of cases: https://splc.org/2014/08/successful-newspaper-theft-prosecutions/

Comment: @bdb484 Your comparison is nonsense. The vaccine is something that an older person can get without problems, and without paying, and it may very well be given to 13 year olds in a few months. The chemical weapons get an adult into trouble just as much (or more likely more) than a 13 year old.

Comment: Thank you. It was written nonsensically to illustrate the failure in the reasoning behind your argument.

Comment: @gnasher729 it may very well be given to 13 year olds in a few months, but at the moment the FDA has not yet approved it for use in children under 16 (in fact, some vaccines are approved only for people 18 years old or older).  So there is a difference between a 57 year old who lies to get the vaccine when it is restricted to those aged 60 and over for reasons of prioritization and a 13 year old who lies when it's available to everyone for whom the FDA has approved it.

Comment: @bdb484 both of those laws (California and Maryland) allow people to take as many free newspapers as they want unless they are trying to achieve some malevolent end by doing so.  The other cases in the third link similarly have an element of malevolence.